# regex to separate items in a list

Tags: python, regex

I need to separate items from within a list, meaning I have a list of items, but some of the items are also lists. I need some way to separate the lists within the list while keeping all items from the original list.

The input is something like this:

```
['lexapro, losartan, lunesta, hormonal supplements', 'prozac 10mg', 'mesalamine, entiviyo, various vitamin supplements', 'none', 'none', '', 'spironolactone 100mg twice a day', 'zoloft', 'blood pressure medications', 'sleep, cholestral, migrain, phentermine']
```

and I want the output to be:

```
['lexapro', 'losartan', 'lunesta', 'hormonal supplements', 'prozac 10mg', 'mesalamine', 'entiviyo', 'various vitamin supplements', 'none', 'none', 'spironolactone 100mg twice a day', 'zoloft', 'blood pressure medications', 'sleep', 'cholestral', 'migrain', 'phentermine']
```

I have used this:

```
separate = re.findall(r'(\d+)(,\s*\d+)*', medicine_list)
```

with no luck. `medicine_list` is the original list. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you give an example of the input?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Do you want to get all items from a list which also contains sublists of items? Ideally, you should post here your simplified example input, your expected output and your attempt at coding.

Comment: Yep ... welcome. Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is regex use compulsory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is some basic text parsing techniques and only a tiny bit of regex. Here's an example:

```
import re

# Raw data.
orig_meds = [
    'lexapro, losartan, lunesta, hormonal supplements',
    'prozac 10mg',
    'mesalamine, entiviyo, various vitamin supplements',
    'none',
    'none',
    '',
    'spironolactone 100mg twice a day',
    'zoloft',
    'blood pressure medications',
    'sleep, cholestral, migrain, phentermine',
]

# Simple regex to split on commas, optionally followed by spaces.
rgx = re.compile(r', *')

# A set of stuff we might not want to keep.
exclude = {'', 'none'}

# Parse.
meds = [
    m
    for om in orig_meds
    for m in rgx.split(om)
    if m not in exclude
]

# Check.
for m in meds:
    print(m)
```

Output:

```
lexapro
losartan
lunesta
hormonal supplements
prozac 10mg
mesalamine
entiviyo
various vitamin supplements
spironolactone 100mg twice a day
zoloft
blood pressure medications
sleep
cholestral
migrain
phentermine
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using loops and split functionality,

```
medicine_list = ['lexapro, losartan, lunesta, hormonal supplements', 'prozac 10mg', 'mesalamine, entiviyo, various vitamin supplements', 'none', 'none', '', 'spironolactone 100mg twice a day', 'zoloft', 'blood pressure medications', 'sleep, cholestral, migrain, phentermine']

list_of_lists = [w.split(",") for w in medicine_list] # convert to list of lists
print([item for sublist in list_of_lists for item in sublist]) 
#traverse sublists and pick items in them one by one and put them 
#in one final list using list comprehension
```